# Web scraping using UIpath

Tags: automation, ui-automation, uipath, rpa

Hi friends i'm new to uipath and i tried doing web scraping but it giving an error (error H RESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.)
so please help me out of this problem.
Thanks
Faiyaz.

Comment: i have faced this error few times, i used to restart the studio or sometime even the machine. try this out.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities that could cause this issue.

1. If you're using a web browser that isn't Internet Explorer (such as Chrome or Firefox) then I would suggest uninstalling the Extension and Reinstalling as this has caused issues for me before
2. Check that .net is installed on your machine and it is updated to the latest version. I've had activities stop working when there has been an update available (although not sure why this happens)
3. Check your selector.I have experienced production automations that have needed selectors changing several months in due to a website changing slightly.

Are you able to provide your workflow/project that is causing this error as I can have a look through it and try and replicate the error

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities are :

1. You have some browser extensions that are making troubles. Uninstall all modules.
2. You can add delay before you activity in the case of some part of the page is loaded by javascript.

Source : https://forum.uipath.com/t/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-uipath-studio-community/530/8